# Cassandra Reads seem to slow

Tags: database, performance, cassandra, latency, nosql

I was profiling an application that uses Cassandra and it turned out that reads were the bottleneck. At closer inspection it seems they take way to long, I would really appreciate some help in understanding why.

The application reads always the whole set of rows for a given partition key (the query is of the form `SELECT * FROM table WHERE partition_key = ?`). Unsurprisingly, the read time is `O(number of rows for partition key)`, however the constant, seems way to high. After examining the query plan it turns out that the majority of time is spent on the "merging data from mem and sstables".

This step takes over 200ms for a partition key of ~5000 rows, where a row consists of 9 columns, and is less than 100 bytes. Given the read throughput of a SSD, reading sequentially 0.5MB should happen instantaneously.

Actually, I doubt this is to do with I/O at all. The machine used to have a spinning disk which was replaced with the SSD it has now. The change had no impact on query performance. I think there is something very involved in Cassandra processing or how it reads the data of disk that makes this operation very expensive.

Merging from more than one SSTable or iterating over tombstoned cells does not explain this. First of all, it should take milliseconds, second of all this is happening consistently, regardless if it is 2 or 4 SSTables and whether there are or not tombstoned cells.

**To give some background:**

*Hardware:* The machine that is running Cassandra is an 8 core, bare metal and SSD backed. I query it from cqlsh on the machine, the data is stored locally. There is no other load on it and looking at iostats, there is also barely any i/o.

*Data model:* The partition key, `PK`, is of `text` type, the primary key is a composite of the partition key and a `bigint` column `K`, and the rest are 7 mutable columns. The schema creation command is listed below.

```
CREATE TABLE inboxes (
  PK text,
  K bigint,
  A boolean,
  B boolean,
  C boolean,
  D boolean,
  E bigint,
  E bigint,
  F int,
  PRIMARY KEY (PK, K)
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (K DESC));
```

This is an example trace, with 3 SSTable involved, an a quite large number of tombstones.

```
activity                                                                                  | timestamp    | source      | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------
                                                                        execute_cql3_query | 03:14:07,507 | 10.161.4.77 |              0
                            Parsing select * from table where PK = 'key_value' LIMIT 10000;| 03:14:07,508 | 10.161.4.77 |            123
                                                                       Preparing statement | 03:14:07,508 | 10.161.4.77 |            244
                                                 Executing single-partition query on table | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1155
                                                              Acquiring sstable references | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1173
                                                               Merging memtable tombstones | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1195
                                                            Key cache hit for sstable 2906 | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1231
                                               Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1240
                                                            Key cache hit for sstable 1533 | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1550
                                               Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1561
                                                            Key cache hit for sstable 1316 | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1867
                                               Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 03:14:07,509 | 10.161.4.77 |           1878
                                                Merging data from memtables and 3 sstables | 03:14:07,510 | 10.161.4.77 |           2180
                                                  Read 5141 live and 1944 tombstoned cells | 03:14:07,646 | 10.161.4.77 |         138734
                                                                          Request complete | 03:14:07,742 | 10.161.4.77 |         235030
```

Comment: Paste the trace if possible

Comment: @RussS updated a question with an example trace. This one is actually a bit faster, but still the two last elements of the call take way to long in my opinion.

Comment: 1. What is the response time when you use some existing partition id? Cassandra must go through memory parts, sstables and tombsones and it also uses bloom filters which can take some time when nothing is found. 2. What is the structure of your data? Is there a lot of updates, deletes etc. in all data. As everything is immutable in cassandra, a lot of items can be touched to find out that nothing was found.

Comment: @MartinPodval there are hardly any deletes, quite a few updates/inserts. As I said i/o doesn't really register (so no bottleneck there), load on the box is minimal and in the trace I gave it is the reading and processing when data is found that takes time. You read < 1MB, all merge operations should be linear and somehow they take > 200ms. For comparison, on the same class of box, sorting 5000 objects while it is serving 5000req/s has a p99 of 7ms.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Zanson 1.2.15 I believe

Answer (score 2):

You're not just "reading sequentially 0.5MB", you're asking Cassandra to turn it into rows, filter out tombstones (deleted rows), and turn it into a resultset.  0.04ms per row is pretty reasonable; my rule of thumb is 0.5ms per 10 rows for an entire query.

Remember that Cassandra optimizes for short requests suitable for online applications; 10 to 100 row resultsets are typical.  There is no parallelization within a single query.

Comment: Any chance of getting more detailed data on the ops you described? The reason I'm asking is because I got metrics on the application that consumes the result of the query. It has to deserialize the result sent over the network, transform it into its domain representation, sort the rows in a different order, apply several filters and finally serialize it again. Yet it just adds an order of magnitude less.

Comment: I don't understand the question; can you clarify?

Comment: basically the trace I added states that merging 3 SSTables and 1 Memtable (together consisting of ~6000 objects) takes 135ms and then reading that (to return ~5000 objects) takes additional 1000ms. I would be curious to get a more fine grained image of what these two steps consist of and how much the substeps take.